# How to set the proper type of a React Context?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have:

```
interface AccountContextProps {
  accountInfo: AccountInfo | null;
  setAccountInfo: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<AccountInfo | null>>;
  isAccountInfoLoading: Boolean;
}

const AccountContext = React.createContext<AccountContextProps>({
  accountInfo: null,
  setAccountInfo: () => undefined,
  isAccountInfoLoading: false,
});

const AccountProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [accountInfo, setAccountInfo] = useState(null);
  const [isAccountInfoLoading, setIsAccountInfoLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchAccountInfo = async (accountApiUrl, authenticationSystem) => {
    initAccountClient(accountApiUrl, authenticationSystem);
    const accountInfoResponse: AccountInfo = await getAccountInfo();
    setAccountInfo(accountInfoResponse);
  };
```

But the `setAccountInfo` has a lint error:

```
Argument of type 'AccountInfo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<null>'.ts(2345)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See the **problem** section in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71157065/typescript-not-assignable-to-type-never-ts2345/71157912#71157912). It's the same problem and the principle of the solution is the same, but the specifics (as in the type you pass in to the type parameter) are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding your `fetchAccountInfo` function (because you haven't provided enough info about it), this is how to correctly type the remaining code you've shown:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-uoWrADZxokEYABilzjaLldr-Cb7e7y7cA9HkAFqgfaoAOSLELe2yUKog4YBMY55BO5Q4NecDAu48Gch8wFrOhEGzE+eG5FBkBIl2WH9oE1SoCwMB4FAloUowqAZoSxL8AAdJqOp6nAWpyngGD5AgCDPts0alnS9aVjGuFlrkgSBC8TEgQgdpmha8IgXAhw9qiuIkjAnFhNx9RKagBaUUAA)

```ts
import {
  default as React,
  createContext,
  useState,
  type Dispatch,
  type ReactElement,
  type ReactNode,
  type SetStateAction,
} from 'react';

type AccountInfo = unknown;

interface AccountContextProps {
  accountInfo: AccountInfo | null;
  setAccountInfo: Dispatch<SetStateAction<AccountInfo | null>>;
  isAccountInfoLoading: Boolean;
}

const AccountContext = createContext<AccountContextProps>({
  accountInfo: null,
  setAccountInfo: () => undefined,
  isAccountInfoLoading: false,
});

const AccountProvider = ({ children }: { children?: ReactNode }): ReactElement => {
  const [accountInfo, setAccountInfo] = useState<AccountInfo | null>(null);
  const [isAccountInfoLoading, setIsAccountInfoLoading] = useState(false);

  // const fetchAccountInfo = async (accountApiUrl, authenticationSystem) => {
  //   initAccountClient(accountApiUrl, authenticationSystem);
  //   const accountInfoResponse: AccountInfo = await getAccountInfo();
  //   setAccountInfo(accountInfoResponse);
  // };

  return (
    <AccountContext.Provider value={{accountInfo, isAccountInfoLoading, setAccountInfo}}>
      {children}
    </AccountContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is great - thank you. How would I set the `fetchAccountInfo` in the `cont AccountContext`?

Comment: @Shamoon I'm not sure I understand your question. If it relates to the commented code: I have no idea what any of that code is: you haven't provided definitions for any of the functions or the values and types that they use.